# Why patch.dict does not work when used as decorator?

Tags: python, testing, decorator, patch

I have a project with a config file in `__init__.py` file of the main directory. The file could be accessed via `project_name.config`. I want to patch the config for tests.

I am patching with the following command: `mock.patch.dict(project_name.config, {'key': 'test_val'})`. `mock` is from `unittest`.

When I try to patch it using `with` inside test function everything works fine but when I try to patch it using decorator patching does not work.

So what is wrong with the decorator?

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue - did you figure this out?